Polarization Under Periodic Boundary Condition
I have a state given as,
$$|{\psi_{0k}}\rangle = \exp(-ik\cdot \hat{r}) |\psi_0\rangle$$
where $k = \frac{2\pi}{L} $ and $ |\psi_{0k}\rangle$ is the PBC ground eigenstate of Hamiltonian $$\hat{H_k}= \frac{1}{2m} \sum _{i=1}^N(p_i + \hbar k)^2 + \hat{v}.$$
Now using the identity, one can write,
$$\partial_k \text{ln} \langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle = \frac{\langle\psi_0|\partial_k \psi_{0k}\rangle}{\langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle}.$$
Now, there is a statement "$\langle\psi_0|\partial_k \psi_{0}\rangle$ is purely imaginary, then leading order expansion in $k $  gives,"
$$i\langle\psi_0|\partial_k \psi_{0}\rangle \cdot  k\approx -\text{Im ln}\langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle $$
Which eventually relates to Polarization (defined dipolemoment per unit volume) in extended system under PBC.
I tried it by expanding the $\langle\psi_0|\partial_k \psi_{0k}\rangle$ and could not really arrive at the final result.
I am not able to get how $\langle\psi_0|\partial_k \psi_{0}\rangle$ is purely imaginary and How the expansion leads to the final result written in last equation. Any help would be much appreciated!

This is a standard single-particle QM thing: since $\frac{\hbar}{i}\partial_k$ is the momentum operator and hence Hermitian, its expectation values are necessarily real. Strip off the $i$, and you get something that's purely imaginary.

But how does expansion leads to final expression written above? @march

I think the trick here is that you should expand the denominator using the exponential expansion in your first equation and then consider just first order terms in k

@Ruffolo I don't think it will lead to anything. I have tried it, but it doesn't give me anything useful!
